# Are these questions duplicates?

Tags: discussion, flagging, exact-duplicates

Apologies if this is a meta-duplicate (I did a search but couldn't find a similar situation).

I answered [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/670342/56960) yesterday. Today the OP posted [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671099/induction-of-a-i) (without crediting me, though I'm not sure if there's a problem with that) as a new question. I flagged the new question as a duplicate, but now I'm not sure if I was correct in doing so.

Comment: I agree that they are duplicates: The second is asking for clarification of your answer of the first question. This should be done through comments (noting that the user already asked a follow-up question in the comments to you), or by editing the original question. (Also, as an update, the question is now closed as duplicate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to make this answered: the two questions mentioned in the post are now marked as duplicates.